# Autoshipping module outputting HTML Code in one storeview

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, extensions, phtml

I have a weird issue with https://github.com/integer-net/Autoshipping module.

Though it works fine in most of my stores/storeviews, in one of the stores/storeviews the output of template/checkout/cart/country.phtml is shown as HTML instead of processed as HTML.

This is what I get:
[image]
<sub>(source: [smarterliving.nl](https://media.smarterliving.nl/stackexchange/autoshipping1.png))</sub>  .

While the output should be like this: 
[image]
<sub>(source: [smarterliving.nl](https://media.smarterliving.nl/stackexchange/autoshipping2.png))</sub>  .

Now why is this happening? Why is Magento outputting a .phtml like this?

This is the content of the .phtml file:

```
<?php /** @var $this IntegerNet_Autoshipping_Block_Country */ ?>

<?php echo $this->__('Shipping cost to', $this->getShippingCostPageUrl()) ?>

<?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getSelectedCountryId(), 'country_id', 'autoshipping_country') ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('autoshipping_country').observe('change', function() {
    window.location = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('autoshipping/country/select') ?>?country_id=' + $F('autoshipping_country');
})
</script>
```

So all stores/storeviews are:

- in the same installation
- using the same template

The **only difference** is that the store and storeviews I get this error on are using https://github.com/sitewards/B2BProfessional to disable pricing info and shopping cart for not logged in users. Obviously I get this error while logged in.

I have to assume that there is some incompatibility between integernet_autoshipping and sitewards_b2bprofessional, but what would it be, why is it? More importantly: how do I troubleshoot this?

**Update:** I have tried to see what happens when I would disable the sitewards_b2bprofessional extension, but the problems stays in this specific website and both its storeviews.

**Update 2:** The line in country.phtml that gives the troubles is: 
    getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getSelectedCountryId(), 'country_id', 'autoshipping_country') ?>

Specifically the $this-getCountryHtmlSelect(). This leads back to app/code/community/IntegerNet/Autoshipping/Helper/Data.php. 
The contents of this file are:

```
class IntegerNet_Autoshipping_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
public function getCountryHtmlSelect($defValue=null, $name='country_id', $id='country', $title='Country')
{
    if (is_null($defValue)) {
        $defValue = $this->getCountryId();
    }
    $cacheKey = 'DIRECTORY_COUNTRY_SELECT_STORE_'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
    if (Mage::app()->useCache('config') && $cache = Mage::app()->loadCache($cacheKey)) {
        $options = unserialize($cache);
    } else {
        $options = $this->getCountryCollection()->toOptionArray();
        if (Mage::app()->useCache('config')) {
            Mage::app()->saveCache(serialize($options), $cacheKey, array('config'));
        }
    }
    $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
        ->setName($name)
        ->setId($id)
        ->setTitle(Mage::helper('directory')->__($title))
        ->setClass('validate-select')
        ->setValue($defValue)
        ->setOptions($options)
        ->getHtml();
    return $html;
}
}
```

**Update 3**: One would think the problem is in this file. However, if I enable template-hints for this storeview AND I comment out the line that calls this function in country.phtml, the actual template hint is not rendered but output as HTML as well:

```
<div style="position:relative; border:1px dotted red; margin:6px 2px; padding:18px 2px 2px 2px; zoom:1;"> <div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; padding:2px 5px; background:red; color:white; font:normal 11px Arial; text-align:left !important; z-index:998;" onmouseover="this.style.zIndex='999'" onmouseout="this.style.zIndex='998'" title="frontend/foundation/default/template/checkout/cart/country.phtml">frontend/foundation/default/template/checkout/cart/country.phtml</div> Shipping cost to NL </div>
```

Currently I'm clueless as to why Magento is behaving this way.

Comment: `window.location = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('autoshipping/country/select') ?>?country_id=' + $F('autoshipping_country');` In this line one `?` is extra.. remove it and check

Comment: @GirishSH this ? is part of the url and should be there. Not trying to be pigheaded I did try it of course, but it actually breaks the code in the other stores.

Comment: No idea about this issue, I gone through the code in Github. Not getting whats wrong there. i read the issues of the integer-net/Autoshipping
 Github repo. Here: https://github.com/integer-net/Autoshipping/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue kindly raise an issue in github, Author may help you out.(As some issues are resolved there)

Comment: @GirishSH thx, but I'm not going to raise an issue there if I'm even not sure it's an issue of this extension. It might be sitewards b2b or even just magento that screws up here. I need to find that out first.

Comment: OK Sure. you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

check line 60:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getTotal()->getTitle()) ?>
```

*(last else)*

and change to:

```
<?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?>
```

Worked for me.